# log4j - log4j-core update

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

I have updated my log4j version from 1.2.17 to log4j-core-2.17.1, this is for the log4jshell vulnerability fix.

While building the code, I am getting the cannot find PatternLayout and ConsoleAppender error message.

I should not have other any log4j version other than log4j-core-2.17.1 in the war file, so I have excluded lo4j in the slf4j dependency in pom.xml file

Please know how to fix this error.

**Code Snippet**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.PatternLayout;

import jxl.common.Logger;

public class Booking {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Booking.class);

    public static boolean isChecked(String[] includeProps) {

        logger.info("Start of method");
    return true;

    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.36</version>
   <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.36</version>
</dependency>
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout
log4j.logger.requestLogger=debug, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.requestLogger=false
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.File=/apps/opt/logs/App.log
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%24F:%t:%L] - %m%n
```

**Error message**

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class PatternLayout

cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class ConsoleAppender

[ERROR] symbol: class variable Logger
```

Comment: Log4J version 1.x is completely different from version 2.x, and was not vulnerable to Log4Shell.

Comment: If you do want to upgrade, then the Log4J 2.x project [has instructions](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html).

Comment: I agree, but log4j 1.x is not allowed in my org and it is considered an outdated version

Comment: You are clearly performing some programmatic configuration in your code, you should share the code that has compile errors. Remark that Log4j2 is not binary compatible with Log4j 1.x (they are different projects), but `log4j-1.2-api` provides _some_ binary compatibility.

Comment: @Vani - so follow the upgrade guide that I linked. It's not as simple as changing the JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Change your imports as follows:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout;
```

This is because 2.x.x version of log4j had major structure changes.